# Probability density function of a complex-valued random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to understand the concept of complex-valued random variables, but I'm struggling. If you consider two real-valued random variables $U$ and $V$ with values $u$ and $v$ and the joint random variable $UV$ with values $(u,v)$ then under the following transformation of random variable $UV$ to random variable $ZW$
$$z=u+iv$$
$$w=u$$
the probability density function of $ZW$ is (Jacobian determinant =1)
$$p_{ZW}(z,w)=p_{UV}(z-iw,w)$$
and the marginal probability density function $p_{Z}(z)$ is then given by
$$p_{Z}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{p_{UV}(z-iw,w)}dw$$
Is this the probability density function of complex-valued random variable $Z$?

Comment: Without taking into account anything like a Jacobian at all, just begin by first _defining_ what you mean by the probability density function of a complex-valued random variable $Z$ and perhaps relate it to the cumulative probability distribution function $F_Z(z)$.  If $Z$ were a _real_ random variable, then $$F_Z(z) = P\{Z \leq z\}.$$  What is the corresponding definition  when $Z$ is complex?  What is the meaning of $Z \leq z$ for complex numbers?

Comment: [This book](http://books.google.be/books/about/Statistical_Optics.html?id=GBtoQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) tells me that complex-valued random variable $Z$ is considered to be the joint random variable of $U$ and $V$ that takes values $z=u+iv$. On the other hand they define $$F_{Z}(z)=P\{U\leq u,V\leq v\}$$

Comment: This would be the definition of the cumulative probability distribution function of any joint random variable. However, this is a particular joint variable because $z=u+iv$. Hence I was considering the transformation of random variable $UV$ to include this particularity, but I'm sure this is wrong as I didn't find anything like it in the books I've read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complex number is treated as 2-d real vector here.